# Returning multiple fetched users

Tags: python, django

I have a view which fetches multiple users from a database based on passed in skills. It works almost as desired except if it returns more than one user it only passes back the most recently fetched user. How do I aggregate fetched users to be passed back to the template. I've tried passing them back as a list but they didn't appear.

Here is my code:

```
form = FilterFreelancerForm(request.POST)
        filtered_skills = set((request.POST.getlist('skills_select')))

        match_fl = Freelancer.object.annotate(c=Count('skills')).filter(c=len(filtered_skills))
        candidate_freelancers = None

        for skill in filtered_skills:
            candidate_freelancers = match_fl.filter(skills=skill)

        freelancers = None

        for freelancer in candidate_freelancers:
            freelancers = User.objects.filter(freelancer=freelancer.id)

    return render(request, 'freelancestudent/browsefreelancers.html', {'freelancers': freelancers,
                                                                       'filter_form': form})
```

I previously had this:

```
    freelancers = []

    for freelancer in candidate_freelancers:
        freelancers.append(User.objects.filter(freelancer=freelancer.id))
```

which returns nothing to the template.

Comment: You haven't done anything with a list at all; you've defined a single variable, `freelancers`, which you override each time through the loop. For the same reason, `candidate_freelancers` only contains the freelancers with the final skill from filtered_skills.

Comment: I've added the code which contained the list which did nothing since you didn't take my word that I'd tried it.

Comment: You did not understand, what `candidate_freelancers = match_fl.filter(skills=skill)`is doing in the for loop is assigning one item to the variable `candidate_freelancers`. It should be a ¿list?, and change that line with `candidate_freelancers.append(match_fl.filter(skills=skill))`

Comment: And same thing with `freelancers` in your code. Are you sure you're getting something into 'filtered_skills'. Also you're not using `match_fl` at all.

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding.  My code above returns two `candidate_freelancers` I want to get the corresponding `User` from each `candidate_freelancer.id` and return them both to the template. What do I return them as? List? Set? QuerySet?

Comment: You're misunderstanding what you're own code is doing, try stepping through with a breakpoint. Are you sure your second snippet of code isn't returning anything, or is it just because that would create a 2d array?

Comment: When I step through `freelancers` looks like `[[<User: user1>], [<User: user2>]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
for freelancer in candidate_freelancers:
    freelancers = User.objects.filter(freelancer=freelancer.id)
```

try:

```
freelancers = User.objects.filter(freelancer__in=[freelancer.id for freelancer in candidate_freelancers])
```

out:

```
[<User: user1>, <User: user2>]
```